# Finitists reject the Axiom of Infinity - are there groups who reject the others?

Tags: logic, soft-question, set-theory, philosophy

I've seen rejections of the Axiom of Infinity. This is called finitism. Some ultrafinitists even add the negation of the Axiom of Infinity. Definitely doable.

I've seen rejections of the Axiom of Choice. That would just mean you choose to work in ZF and not ZFC, which is controversial but not unheard of.

I could imagine rejecting the Existence axiom. Then all of your mathematics would be in one big conditional (where $\exists x \ x=x\implies\phi$) for any correct statement derivable in your axiom system (with the axiom $\exists x\ x=x$ removed). I can see a little formalist sparkle in this - you can manipulate all the symbols out there, and your manipulations would result in some truth **if and only if** there's some mathematical object out there you can play with. Maybe there isn't! Maybe there is! But this cuts down on our need to assume something exists and means we can do all of mathematics within logic (rather than making non-logical ontological claims). Does this have a name?

Or, even more bizarrely; do some people reject Comprehension, or Specification, or Pairing or whatever? Is this just obviously regressive thinking? Can we derive much much less?

I'm most familiar with ZF(C) and Peano Arithmetic, so I'd appreciate examples to do with those (maybe there's some niche axiom system and an even more niche modification where you reject 17 out of 199 axioms, but this isn't really what I'm looking for).

Comment: Look up "predicativism."

Comment: If you're open to rejecting a standard axiom of logic and not just one of set theory, there are the intuitionists.

Comment: Especially if logic is up for grabs too, this question seems too unfocussed for MSE. But one example is non-well founded set theory, which rejects the axiom of regularity. But even this example has multiple variants.

Comment: $ZFC$ with Replacement Axiom schema removed (is it called $ZC$?) is a foundational theory in which you can still do a lot of mathematics (as far as I know). Same for $KP_{\omega}$ (Kripke-Platek set theory with infinity)

Comment: See [Alternative Axiomatic Set Theories](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/settheory-alternative/) and [Non-wellfounded Set Theory](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/nonwellfounded-set-theory/) and [Set Theory: Constructive and Intuitionistic ZF](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/set-theory-constructive/).